# First-order number theory : Usage of 'and' symbol?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Whats the difference between the statements

∀x ∀y F

&

∀x ∧ ∀y F

Also, are these two statements equivalent?

∀x ∧ x>0 F

∀x x>0 F

Thanks.

Comment: The statements with an "and" after the quantifier don't make any sense. $\forall x$ is not a statement, so it doesn't make sense to take the "and" of it and something else.

Comment: So it wouldn't make sense even if, say, x>0 ∧ ∀ y F, i.e we use it after the and?

Comment: Yes, it would make sense to say $x \gt 0 \wedge \forall y F$.  This is an expression with $x$ free.  It is false if $\forall y F$ is false.  If $\forall y F$ is true, the truth value of the whole expression depends on whether $x$ is greater than zero.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you. Edit : Removed my question. Too unrelated. Perhaps I'll make a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We write $\forall x \varphi(x)$ where $\varphi$ is a proposition. $\forall x$ is one quantifier, and it is not a statement in and of itself. Therefore, $\forall x \land \forall y F$ makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you. Would something like x>0 ∧ ∀ x F be valid? I'm trying to write the notation  'u/{x} is an element of w', but I'm having to introduce several quantifiers, so I'm confused about the places I need to use 'and'.. do I need to use 'and' if I say something like 'for all u such that u is an element of w, there exists x such that x is an element of u'?' in first order number theory?

Comment: In first order number theory you can't formally talk about sets of naturals.  You can in set theory.  Your statement is saying that all the elements of $w$ are nonempty.  The simple way to say that is $\emptyset \not \in w$.  The (slightly informal) translation of what you wrote is $\forall u \in w \exists x (x \in u)$.  A more formal translation would be $\forall u (u\in w \implies \exists x (x \in u))$

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, both pairs of statements are equivalent.  If you look at your rules for constructing sentences, I suspect that the official way is $\forall x (\forall y F)$ or something like that to indicate that the range of the quantifiers is only $F$.  This would come in if you wrote $\forall x \forall y F(x,y)\wedge G(x,y)$  The $x$ and $y$ in $G(x,y)$ might be bound or they might be free.  The versions that I have seen without parentheses would only apply the quantifiers to $F(x,y)$ so you should read this as $\left(\forall x \forall y F(x,y)\right)\wedge G(x,y)$ and this is an expression with $x$ and $y$ free in $G(x,y)$ but bound in $F(x,y)$ (which I think is terrible practice because it makes your reader sort out what is going on.  Much better to write $\left(\forall w \forall z F(w,z)\right)\wedge G(x,y)$.  This is logically equivalent, but the range of the quantifiers if obvious.)  For your second, what you really mean is $\forall x (x \gt 0 \implies F)$.  I have seen this abbreviated to $\forall x\gt 0\ F$